# How to change View width and height with Use ObjectAnimator property scaleX and scaleY?

Tags: objectanimator

I use ObjectAnimator to change view scaleX and scaleY. `

```
AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(recyclerView, "scaleX", 0.5f);
ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(recyclerView, "scaleY", 0.5f);
animatorSet.setDuration(50);
animatorSet.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
animatorSet.play(scaleX).with(scaleY);
animatorSet.start();
```

` 
when the scale change end, the view's width and height not change. So my problem come, in the layout, the scale view has change small only half, but the width not change, how i can do something to change the with with scale?